# VueJS access data values from console

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, console

I am beginner with Vue and i didn't find answer for my question...
I use Vue over this CDN:
https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js

And this is my VueJS testing code:

```
const { createApp } = Vue

createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            'key': 'VueJS is working now',
            'question': 'answer',
            'main_attributes': {},
        }
    },
    
created() {
    this.key = 'sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg';
    console.log(this.key);
}
}).mount('#project')
```

And i wish to access these properties (key, question) outside of this instance.
How can i do that? The created function works just fine and no problem with that.
I tried everything i could think of...
I think there should be easy way to do easy thing like:

```
createApp.$get('question'); // returns 'answer'
```

or:

```
createApp.data.question; // returns 'answer'
```

But i can find the way to do this seemingly easy thing..
My further goal is to update Vue data from AJAX function..

So.. i'm pretty sure there should be easy way to access VueJS from console or from other place in my code..

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All properties of the app are accessible from the object returned by `createApp`, you just need to assign it.

```
import { createApp } from "vue";

const app = createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      key: "VueJS is working now",
      question: "answer",
      main_attributes: {}
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.key = "sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg";
  }
}).mount("#project");

console.log(app.key); // logs 'sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg'
```